# Fixar posição de uma página

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma página que dentro dela tem outra, essa página interna é colocada em um iframe, eu preciso que ela fique em uma determinada posição e não ela inteira. width="250" height="350" scrolling="no" . Eu não posso fazer isso no iframe pois não tenho permissão então coloquei essa iframe dentro de uma div. Já tentei isso mas não funciona:

```
var frm_doc = document.getElementById("frm"); 
//frm_doc.documentElement.scrollTop = 500;
//document.getElementById("frm").contentWindow.scrollTo(100, 500); 
frm_doc.contentWindow.scrollTop(500, 500);
```

O problema é que preciso fixar a posição vertical dessa página incluída na outra, pois só quero mostrar para o usuário somente um quadro que faz uma determinada função.

Comment: Aí precisa de aplicar CSS. Pode explicar melhor o cenário que tem e como pretende que fique? e o que já tentou?

Comment: Eu tenho uma página que dentro dela tem outra, essa página interna é colocada em um iframe, eu preciso que ela fique em uma determinada posição e não ela inteira. width="250" height="350" scrolling="no" . Eu não posso fazer isso no iframe pois não tenho permissão então coloquei essa iframe dentro de uma div. Já tentei isso mas não funciona  var frm_doc = document.getElementById("frm");
        //frm_doc.documentElement.scrollTop = 500;        
        //document.getElementById("frm").contentWindow.scrollTo(100, 500);
        frm_doc.contentWindow.scrollTop(500, 500);

Comment: De acordo com Sergio. Precisamos saber por exemplo a quem pertence as paginas. A 1a esta  no servidor de vc? E a segunda? E porque vc quere mostrar somente ume parte? No caso de mostra somente um elemento, acho melhor ler a pagina em PHP, filtrar dados e depois enviar com echo o que vc quer mostrar. Mas depende muito da situação. Entao, tenta explicar melhor para que podemos ajudar melhor. :)

Comment: A primeira sim está no meu servidor e a segunda não, ela possui uma função em um botão de que preciso. Eu só preciso que esse botão fique na minha e use ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não tem permissão para fazer isso dentro da iFrame então tem de mudar a posição da iFrame dentro da `div` que a envolve.

Nesse caso sugiro que dê `position: relative;` à div que está à volta da iFrame e `position: fixed;` à propria iFrame. Aí pode fazer assim com JavaScript:
<sub>(caso não queira fazer com CSS que é ainda malhor)</sub>

```
document.querySelector('iframe').style.top = '-300px'; // ou outro valor que queira
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/aergmkwv/